# Functions suitable for the complex step method

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

In numerics there is the so called complex step method. One approximates the derivative at $x \in \mathbb{R}$ via

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \mathrm{Re}\frac{f(x+ih)}{ih} \approx f'(x) $$

Consider Funtions $f \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, such that $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Equality holds if $f$ is holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $x$.

> What is the weakest (non trivial) assumption such that one has equality in above approximation? Are there conditions that are necessary?

Comment: When you start asking questions of that type, you should better investigate automatic differentiation and there the direct forward mode, also called dual numbers, as that only requires the simple differentiabilty to work. Misusing complex numbers in this form is only an easy hack to approximate dual numbers where operator overloading is not but complex number types are available

Comment: This question arose in a discussion with some friends. And I told them that they cannot assume the equality for that many functions. To underline this I thought of it but couldn‘t come up with necessary conditions or assumptions except holomorphic function or a Taylor like expression. I’m not really that intrested in numerical methods to approximate the Derivate.

Comment: the weakest assumption is that the equality holds.

Comment: thanks for the assumption. i might exclude this from the question :)

Comment: Do we assume $h\to 0$ through real values?

Comment: I am not really sure but everywhere i read about the complex step method it is for real $h$. So yes you might assume that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thm: Suppose $D(a,r)$ is an open disc centered at $a\in \mathbb R,$ and $f=u+iv : D(a,r) \to \mathbb C.$ Assume $f$ is real on $(a-r,a+r).$ Then

$$\tag 1f_x(a) =\lim_{h\to 0,\, h\in \mathbb R}\text { Re } \frac{f(a+ih)}{ih}$$

if and only if $u_x(a)=v_y(a).$

Proof: Note that because $v=0$ on $(a-r,a+r),$ $f=u$ on this interval. Thus $u_x(a)$ exists iff $f_x(a)$ exists, and the two are the same.

Observe the following:

$$\tag 2\text { Re } \frac{f(a+ih)}{ih} = \text { Re } \frac{u(a+ih) + iv(a+ih)}{ih} = \frac{v(a+ih)}{h}=\frac{v(a+ih)-v(a)}{h}.$$

For $\implies,$ we are given the limit of $(2)$ as $h\to 0$ exists and equals $f_x(a)=u_x(a).$ Therefore the limit on the right of $(2)$ exists, which by definition is $v_y(a).$ For $\impliedby,$ we are given $v_y(a)=u_x(a)=f_x(a).$ $(2)$ then makes it clear that $(1)$ holds. The proof of the theorem is complete.

Thus when we know $f$ is real on $(a-r,a+r,)$ only one half of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, namely $u_x(a)=v_y(a),$ need hold for $(1)$ to hold. This is definitely weaker than the requirement that $f$ be holomorphic at $a.$ For example, $f(x,y) = x+e^y +iy,$ which is real on the real axis, satisfies $u_x=v_y$ everywhere. However the full CR equations fail everywhere.